# How to send offline Broadcast message using bridgefy SDK?

Tags: android, offline

Found sample on [Sample-Bridgefy](https://github.com/bridgefy/bridgefy-android-samples), but not able to run successfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just digged through Google and found a better page out [here](https://medium.com/bridgefy/creating-an-offline-messaging-app-with-the-bridgefy-sdk-3940ee4e8b16)

They've mentioned a step by step implementation of this library.
Also an example to refer for code information is [here](https://github.com/bridgefy/bridgefy-android-samples/tree/master/twitter)

Code to handle when connection is online:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ChatViewController * chatController = (ChatViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"openContactChat"])
    {
        // Conversation with a concrete user.
        chatController.online = openStateOnline;
        chatController.userUUID = openUUID;
        NSDictionary *peerInfo = self.peerNamesDictionary[openUUID];
        chatController.deviceName = peerInfo[@"name"];
        chatController.deviceType = (DeviceType)[peerInfo[@"type"] intValue];
        chatController.messages = [self loadMessagesForConversation:openUUID];
        chatController.broadcastType = NO;
    } else
    {
        // Broadcast conversation
        // (the messages will be sent to all available users)
        chatController.online = openStateOnline;
        chatController.userUUID = @"broadcast";
        chatController.messages = [self loadMessagesForConversation:broadcastConversation];
        chatController.broadcastType = YES;
    }

    chatController.chatDelegate =  self;

    self.chatController = chatController;
}
```

And in Offline state:

```
- (void)transmitter:(BFTransmitter *)transmitter
    didDetectDisconnectionWithUser:(NSString *)user
{
    // A disconnection was detected.
    [self discardUUID:user];
    [self.offlinePeers addObject:user];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    if (self.chatController &&
        [self.chatController.userUUID isEqualToString:user])
    {
        //If currently a the related conversation is shown,
        //update the state.
        [self.chatController updateOnlineTo:NO];
    }
}
```

I'd suggest to try referring the page and implement the above code as per your convenience.

Hope that helps.